# Получение данных из input'ов без формы

Tags: php, html

Добрый день! У меня возник такой вопрос, можно ли получать данные из input'ов без формы, чтобы к примеру нажать на ссылку какую-то и данные из input'ов записались в переменные php. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Javascript, AJAX

Comment: А средствами php, html это невозможно?

Comment: хм, а ява скрипт так сложен?) да и пологаю вы вместо кнопки ссылку хотите а не отправку без форм?

Comment: ява скрипт не знаю к сожалению совсем. Это получится, что там надо с базой данной работать еще на ява скрипте... И я хочу не просто ссылку сделать, а хочу чтобы input'ы без формы по нажатию по разным ссылкам (именно по трем разным) записывались в базу данных. Такое возможно на php сделать?

Comment: PHP должен какие данные получить для обработки и сделать с ними что-то? А как получить данные? Только через протоколы HTTP. Если что-то делается в обход нормального хода дел, то нужно как это дело воссоздать искусственно. Тут и приходит на помощь Javascript.

Comment: тогда покажите код на javascript только без фреймворка ajax, как в простейшем случае получить данные из инпута и вывести например в html код. Тогда от этого я оттолкнусь для дальнейших действий. А то я яваскрипт не знаю вовсе.

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="test1" />
    <input type="text" id="test2" />
    <input type="text" id="test3" />
    <br />
    <a href="#" onclick="getInput('test1')">test1</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="getInput('test2')">test2</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="getInput('test3')">test3</a>

    Тут выводим результат
    <div id="answer"></div>
    <script>
        var answer = document.getElementById('answer');
        function getInput(inputId) {
            var element = document.getElementById(inputId);
            answer.innerText = element.value;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: спасибо за пример! А как сделать к примеру передачу данных Input'а из яваскрипт в переменную php? как связать два языка программирования?

Comment: тут AJAX вступает в силу

Comment: без него разве никак? Не люблю я фреймворки, вообще можно по идее все и на яваскрипте сделать, раз в ajax есть такая возможность.

Comment: можно конечно. Но изобретать велосипед тоже не дело

Comment: вообщем я переделал так: создал форму, в ней несколько input'ов, но вместо кнопки субмит несколько ссылок разного назначения. Как можно сделать так, чтобы они передавали данные из input'ов в переменные?

Answer (score 2):

Итак, решение простое:

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('myform').submit(); return false;">Отправить</a>
```

При условии, что в браузере включен JS.